# Mongoose: OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `users` model once compiled

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next-auth

I'm using Mongoose to manage a MongoDB server, and all other solutions with this error have not helped. The models aren't defined anywhere else, and the only issue I can think of is that the tables/models already exist on the MongoDB server, but other than that I've never had this issue before.

My current code is this:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology:true});

const users = require('../../models/Users.schema')
const accounts = require('../../models/Account.schema')

export default (req, res) => {
    users.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function (err, user) {
        console.log(user)
        accounts.findOne({ userId: user._id }, function (err, account) {
            console.log(account)
          return res.json({
            error: false,
            body: account
          })
        })
    })
}
```

Users schema (mainly for an example, this issue happens with all schemas)

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const usersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    image: String,
    createdAt: Date,
    updatedAt: Date
})

module.exports.users = mongoose.model('users', usersSchema);
```

What I'm trying to do is get the data from [NextAuth](https://next-auth.js.org) that isn't provided normally, such as the `accessToken` (`session.accessToken` is not the right accessToken).

I'm not sure what to do, and I'll take any help I can get.
Thanks!

Comment: it would be interesting if you reduce it to a MWE, scope it a bit more, and include the full error. If you can't do it, it means the error is in the interaction with NextAuth, whatever that is

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring because you already have a schema defined, and then you are defining the schema again

Comment: That's not the issue though, it's never been defined anywhere else.